# Drop down menu CSS sectors

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-position, nav, dropdown

I'm a beginner to CSS and HTML. Currently I'm really stuck with the drop down menu, I've searched for an answer for HOURS and I just can't find the error. If I put "position:relative" the submenu shows inside the nav bar, but it should show outside. If I leave "position:absolute" the both

elements overlay, but they are outside of the nav bar how I want it.
And there is of course still the dilemma with de hover-effect; it should show only when the cursor is on the topnav-element.

HTML
    `<body>
        <nav>
        <ul class="topnav">
            <li style="float: right;"><h1>CH</h1></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Studium</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pers&ouml;nlich</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="umfeld.html">Umfeld</a></li>
                    <li><a href="interessen.html">Interessen</a></li>
                        <!--<ul class="subsubnav">
                            <li><a href="Interessen/sport.html">Sport</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Interessen/musik.html">Musik</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>-->
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>`

CSS
`

```html
/*nav*/
nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #99ddff;
}
nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
nav a {
 display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Raleway", Tahoma, sans-serif;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 padding: 1em;
}
nav a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.active {background: #90bed5;
 color: #ffffff; 
}

/*Dropdown Menu*/
ul.subnav {
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
ul.subnav li {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
}
ul.subnav li a {
 padding: 0.2em 1em 1em 0;
 border-bottom: solid white;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.subnav li:hover {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

I would be so glad if someone could help. 
Thank you very much in advance!
Cssie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to hide `ul.subnav` (not just the `li`'s), and target the CSS to show the hidden subnav when you hover an `li` element that has a nested subnav.

```css
/*nav*/
nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #99ddff;
}
nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
nav a {
 display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Raleway", Tahoma, sans-serif;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 padding: 1em;
}
nav a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.active {background: #90bed5;
 color: #ffffff; 
}

/*Dropdown Menu*/
ul ul {
 display: none;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
ul ul li a {
 padding: 0.2em 1em 1em 0;
 border-bottom: solid white;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
   <body>
        <nav>
        <ul class="topnav">
            <li style="float: right;"><h1>CH</h1></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Studium</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pers&ouml;nlich</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="umfeld.html">Umfeld</a></li>
                    <li><a href="interessen.html">Interessen</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Interessen/sport.html">Sport</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Interessen/musik.html">Musik</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It worked :)
And what kind of selector would work for another submenu under the submenu? I tried that and it showed, but I don't know about the hover. "ul li:hover .subsubnav { same as subnav does not work}"

Comment: @Cssie updated my answer. The basic idea is you hide any instance of `ul ul` where the second `ul` will be a submenu. Then when you hover an `li` you show the direct descendent `ul` using the `>` selector.

Comment: I see. Gonna have to practice on these dropdowns, but I get the idea and it seems much less complicated than I imagined it. It worked perfectly.  You're awesome, thanks!

Comment: @Cssie my pleasure!